# I want to disable automatic brightness adjusting, but where is the setting?

Tags: snow-leopard, display

I'm basically trying trying to find this setting: [image: Automatically adjust brightness]

From [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/auto-brightness-in-mountain-lion), but can't find it on this Snow Leopard MacBook. My version of that settings window has the slider, plus a list of resolutions, but not the "auto brightness" checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing an [SMC Reset](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964) to see if the option appears in the Display preference pane?

Also, some information about what operating system and model you're using would be helpful.

Edit: After further research, it appears that the model in question does not have an Ambient Light Sensor (ALS) which is required for the automatic brightness adjustment feature.

Comment: The OS is MacOS 10.6.8 (hence the "Snow Leopard"-tag). It's a MacBook Pro, but I have no idea what iteration, year, etc. It's from 3 years ago, I think.

Comment: Apple labels it as: "MacBook (13-inch, Mid 2010)".

Comment: An SMC Reset did not resolve the issue.

Comment: It looks like that model in particular is lacking an Ambient Light Sensor (ALS) which is a necessary component for the automatic brightness adjustment feature. For that generation, the standard Macbook didn't have an ALS, whereas the Macbook Pro models had it. 

You can find the full technical specs for your model here: http://support.apple.com/kb/SP584

Answer (score -1):

Use the **Fkey** or **Command Key** equivalent to adjust the display brightness.

You may be be more interested in changing the **contrast**

If so go to the system preference - Accessibility ↳  display !

Voila!

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all… "why does my leg hurt when I walk?" Doctor: "just don't walk on it"